# How to adjust the image to meet the minimum requirements and avoid receiving the Telegram API Bad Request error: PHOTO_INVALID_DIMENSIONS?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, telegram, telegram-bot

Summary: Telegram has requirements for images that are sent, and to avoid failures, I add huge white borders far above what would be the minimum necessary. I would like to know how I could create a method so that the image is adjusted at once but with the minimum borders required.

According to the documentation I couldn't understand exactly how I could reach that value, here it is `sendPhoto`:

> Photo to send. Pass a file_id as a String to send a photo that exists
> on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as a String
> for Telegram to get a photo from the Internet, or upload a new photo
> using multipart/form-data. The photo must be at most 10 MB in size.
> The photo's width and height must not exceed 10000 in total. Width and
> height ratio must be at most 20.

My sample code creates this image that generates an error when sending it to Telegram because it does not meet the minimum requirements:

[image]

Currently, the code adds borders above and below a size that I know works, and it looks like this:

```python
def create_image():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f"column_letter_{chr(97 + i)}" for i in range(9)])
    dfi.export(df, 'telegram_image.png', table_conversion="selenium", max_rows=-1)

def adjust_image():
    fil_img = Image.open("telegram_image.png")
    min_img = 600
    difference = min_img - fil_img.size[1]
    new_image = Image.new("RGB", (fil_img.size[0], min_img), (255, 255, 255))
    new_image.paste(fil_img, (0, difference // 2))
    new_image.save("telegram_image.png")
```

[image]

In this additional method I tried, the problem is that the image shrinks and thus the quality also decreases, I don't want the quality to decrease at all, I just want to adjust the edges so that it maintains the original size of the image but fits the minimum necessary proportion:

```python
def adjust_image():
    image = Image.open('telegram_image.png')
    width, height = image.size

    if width / height > 20 or height / width > 20:
        new_width = min(width, height * 20)
        new_height = min(height, width * 20)
        image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save('telegram_image.png', quality=100, subsampling=0)
```

[image]

How would it be possible to create an image adjustment that is not fixed to a specific number of borders to add, and instead adds only the minimum amount necessary?

**Complete Code:**

```python
import dataframe_image as dfi
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

def send_image_telegram(ids_chat, bot_token, text_msg, file_photo, buttons=None, parse_mode=None):
    if not isinstance(ids_chat, list):
        ids_chat = [ids_chat]
    list_for_return = []
    for chat_id in ids_chat:
        telegram_api_url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendPhoto'
        message_data = {
            "chat_id": chat_id,
            "caption": text_msg
        }
        if parse_mode is not None:
            message_data['parse_mode'] = parse_mode
        if buttons is not None:
            message_data['reply_markup'] = json.dumps({'inline_keyboard': buttons})
        with open(file_photo, "rb") as imageFile:
            response = requests.post(telegram_api_url, files={"photo": imageFile}, data=message_data)
            list_for_return.append(json.loads(response.text))
    return list_for_return

def create_image():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f"column_letter_{chr(97 + i)}" for i in range(9)])
    dfi.export(df, 'telegram_image.png', table_conversion="selenium", max_rows=-1)

def adjust_image():
    fil_img = Image.open("telegram_image.png")
    min_img = 600
    difference = min_img - fil_img.size[1]
    new_image = Image.new("RGB", (fil_img.size[0], min_img), (255, 255, 255))
    new_image.paste(fil_img, (0, difference // 2))
    new_image.save("telegram_image.png")

def to_telegram():
    send = send_image_telegram('123456789','XXXXXXXXXX','test','telegram_image.png')
    if not send[0]['ok'] and send[0]['description'] == 'Bad Request: PHOTO_INVALID_DIMENSIONS':
        adjust_image()
        send_image_telegram('123456789','XXXXXXXXXX','test','telegram_image.png')

def main():
    create_image()
    to_telegram()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Telegram and am not 100% sure I understand your question, but in a nutshell it seems you want to make a 1157x23 image comply with having an aspect ratio less than 20. If you do that by resizing, you will distort the image, so I am suggesting you do it by padding instead - I'm doing it in magenta so you can see what I have added:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from math import ceil
from PIL import Image

# Open original image and get its size
im = Image.open('7r8q3.png')
w, h = im.size

# Calculate new size to comply with a 1:20 aspect ratio
newH = ceil(w/20)

# Create background of new image
padded = Image.new('RGB', (w,newH), 'magenta')

# Paste existing image into new one at vertical midpoint
padded.paste(im, (0,int((newH-h)/2)))
padded.save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

The new image has size 1157x58, which is an aspect ratio of 19.95:1. Obviously you can change the magenta to any other colour you like once you have understood my suggestion.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, a way to readjust the image without losing quality and at the same time without the need to add huge borders when smaller borders would be sufficient. Thank you very much.